# Charging a capacitor through a diode

Tags: diodes, capacitor-charging

I am a student who is trying understand some things.

I read in a book that a capacitor can charge up to battery voltage when connecting in series with a  resistor and battery like this:

[image: Charged capacitor]

Can it charge when I add a diode?

[image: Capacitor charged through diode]

Comment: Welcome! Please try it with a free simulator.

Comment: What do you need to provide to a capacitor for it to charge? Will the diode conduct in that circuit?

Comment: The longer line in the battery symbol is the positive side, so the diode has to be the other way around to pass current to the capacitor.  We normally put the positive supply at the top of the schematic, with negative at the bottom, so your schematic is up-side-down, and therefore a bit confusing...

Comment: Since the current is always in one direction adding a diode does not affect the way the capacitor charges - the diode is always conducting, it just works like a piece of wire (ignoring the voltage drop).

Answer (score 3):

Let's try to make sense of this circuit (with flipped battery). What could have caused you to charge a capacitor through a diode? Maybe you wanted to drop the battery voltage by 0.7 V? If so, let's simulate it.

### Unbiased diode

The circuit is properly connected and the capacitor is charged. But why up to 9 V and not up to 8.3 V as we imagine?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4yESl.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

At the beginning, a sufficiently high current flows and the voltage across the forward-biased diode VF is really 0.7 V. At the end of the process, however, the capacitor is charged almost to the supply voltage. The current drops sharply and very little voltage remains across the diode (remember what a diode IV curve is).

[image: STEP 1a]

[image: STEP 1b]

Our conclusion is that ***at a very small current the voltage across the diode is not 0.7 V but close to zero***. In other words, ***the diode is not properly biased***.

### Biased diode

The remedy is ***to pass an additional current through the diode*** or ***to bias constantly the diode***. For this purpose, we can connect a resistor R2 between the diode and battery.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2feBBSI.png)</sup>

The result is positive - the 0.7 V diode forward voltage is subtracted from the 9 V battery voltage and the capacitor is charged to 8.3 V.

[image: STEP 2a]
[image: STEP 2b]

Remember this trick because it is often used in circuits.

Comment: thanks Sir for your replying

Comment: @Neil, Thanks for your kindness, it rarely happens here. Did you get an idea of ​​the diode and capacitor behavior in this circuit? An even simpler explanation is to imagine the diode as a "dynamic resistor" that changes its resistance as the voltage changes. I could develop this idea if you like.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it will charge the capacitor (assuming it's a real diode and not a magic ideal diode), but very slowly because the diode will be reverse-biased. 100pF is a fairly small capacitance, but the reverse leakage of a diode such as 1N4148 is also rather small. Here is the equivalent of what you have drawn, simulated in LTspice, which you can download and use for free. The only trick is that you should start the supply voltage off at zero (a choice when you select the simulation command). In this case, the model has a reverse leakage of about 1nA. This might be hard to measure on the bench because most multimeters have something like 10MΩ input resistance and that is low enough to almost short out the 100pF capacitor.

[image]

If you flip the voltage source, the curve looks a bit similar but the capacitor charges in tens of microseconds rather than hundreds of milliseconds (and it is more predictable since it mostly depends on the value of R1):

[image]

Comment: Thanks Sir for you replying